# How to Host a Flutter App with Linode.com

Tags: flutter, hosting, serverless, cloud-hosting

I'm interested in hosting my flutter web app on linode.com and also using it as a backend for my flutter mobile apps as a more affordable alternative to Google Firebase and AWS.

I've seen some articles online about using Digital Ocean for flutter apps, but does anyone have an idea of how to use Linode.com for hosting Flutter apps?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Digital Ocean tutorials for Linode.com. The main part of installing your app to server is setting up VPS, installing softwares, and many more are same on every hosting provider. The only difference might be user interface used for creating virtual server instances.